# Multiplying one column by another in pandas dataframe but getting a dtype('<U32') error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I am wanting to multiply each row in one column by the other (**column Line Limit are data type float64**) and return the sum of these.

[image]

```
def pol_stats(df,refcol,linecol,limitcol):
    """Summarise account file."""
    acc_count = len(pd.unique(df[refcol]))
    acc_exp = sum((df[linecol] / 100) * limitcol)
    return (acc_count,acc_exp)

pol_stats(df,'Reference','Line','Limit')
```

But I am getting the error 'ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')'.

I have tried using `float()` or `to_numeric()` on limitcol but still getting an error. Not sure why this would be an issue if both columns are data type float.

Comment: Can you add some data somple? How is used `pol_stats` with this data sample ? `limitcol` is number? Or column name?

Comment: What gives `df.dtypes`?

Comment: Good point - have edited the question and added the data sample and how the function is used to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is instead column `df[limitcol]` was multiple by column name `limitcol`, so solution multiple by string, so raise error:

```
acc_exp = ((df[linecol] / 100) * df[limitcol]).sum()
```